# Flutter: Why is the spacing between the card widgets different

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

The spacing between my Card widgets is apparently randomly different. I'm using a ListView with Cards and for troubleshooting purposes, I have changed the context (Text and Image) to be identical for each Card, but somehow the spacing still appears different.

In the image below you can see that the spacing between Card 2 and Card 3 are much less than the spacing between Card 1 and Card 2.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(MaterialApp(
   home: MyApp(),
 ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 // List data;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text("Nyskördat"),
         backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
       ),
       body: Container(
         child: Center(
           // Use future builder and DefaultAssetBundle to load the local JSON file
           child: FutureBuilder(
               future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                   .loadString('assets/fruits_data.json'),
               builder: (context, snapshot) {
                 // Decode the JSON
                 var fruits = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
                 var now = new DateTime.now();
                 return ListView.builder(
                   // Build the ListView
                   itemCount: fruits == null ? 0 : fruits.length,
                   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                     var currentMonth = fruits[index]['months'].toString();
                     return Card(
                       child: Column(
                         children: <Widget>[
                           if (currentMonth.contains(now.month.toString()))
                             SizedBox(
                               height: 350,
                               width: 600,
                               child: Stack(
                                 children: <Widget>[
                                   if (currentMonth
                                       .contains(now.month.toString()))
                                     //Container(
                                       Image.asset('assets/orange.jpg'),// +
                                     //   fruits[index]['image'].toString()),
                                     //),
                                   if (currentMonth
                                       .contains(now.month.toString()))
                                     Container(
                                       margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                           bottom: 5, left: 5),
                                       child: Align(
                                         alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                         child: Text(
                                           fruits[index]['name'].toString(),
                                           style: TextStyle(
                                               fontFamily: 'DancingScript',
                                               fontSize: 70,
                                               color: Colors.lightBlue),
                                         ),
                                       ),
                                     )
                                 ],
                               ),
                             ),
                         ],
                       ),
                     );
                   },
                 );
               }),
         ),
       ));
 }
}
```

Comment: Does the spacing go away if you replace `Card` with another widget like `Container`?

Answer (score 0):

`Column` inside the `Card` will have children only `if (currentMonth.contains(now.month.toString()))`. Is this condition true for all your `fruits`?
I guess it is not. You did not provide any content for the opposite case, which led to an empty `Card`. And the `Card` widget by default has margin of 4 px, which looks like more empty space to you.

By the way, you don't have to repeat `if (currentMonth.contains(now.month.toString()))` condition down in `Stack` as this whole thing won't be built if the condition is not met the first time.